# Checkboxes set in VBA for PDF not staying checked

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, checkbox, flatten-pdf

Hi All this code works wonderfully in filling out a VA 28-1905 form from a worksheet in excel. However the checkboxes don't remain checked. They are checked when the form initially saves, but when you open it again then the checkboxes aren't check. I don't know how to resolve this. Any help would be appreciated. I don't program all of the time so if you have improvement suggestions that would be awesome as well.

I tried objJSO.flattenpages but I get a NotAllowedError: Security settings prevent access to this property or method. If I stop the code before the save everything is filled out properly, but after save the checkboxes reset to 0.

This code has been adapted from Christos Samaras' code.

```
            'Enable screen flickering.
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'            'All checkboxes to checked
                objAcroApp.Show

                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(22)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(23)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(24)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(25)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(26)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(27)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(28)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(52)).Value = 1



                'Veteran's Vocation Choice set focus
                objAcroApp.Show
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(5)).SetFocus

                Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
                'Application.SendKeys "{Tab}", True
                Application.SendKeys "{right}", True



            'Create the output path with the term and class .pdf
            Dim w
            If x = 4 Then
                w = LastRow
            Else
                w = x - 1
             End If

            refFile = "\" & oSheet & "." & w & ".pdf"

            strPDFOutPath = strPDFOutPath & refFile



            'Save the form as new PDF file.
            objAcroPDDoc.Save 2, strPDFOutPath


            'Close the form without saving the changes.
            objAcroAVDoc.Close True


            'Close the Acrobat application.
            objAcroApp.Exit

            'Release the objects.
            Set objJSO = Nothing
            Set objAcroPDDoc = Nothing
            Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
            Set objAcroApp = Nothing


        Else

            MsgBox "Could not open the file!", vbCritical, "File error"

            'Close the Acrobat application.
            objAcroApp.Exit

            'Release the objects and exit.
            Set objAcroAVDoc = Nothing
            Set objAcroApp = Nothing
            Exit Sub

        End If

    i = w
    Next i

End With

Next p

    'Inform the user that forms were filled.
    MsgBox "All forms were created successfully!", vbInformation, "Finished"



End Sub
```

Comment: edit your code to the relevant pieces. code dumps detract people from trying to help. also, what happens we check the box manually and save and close, does it stick?

Comment: also - i see this:             `'Close the form without saving the changes.
            objAcroAVDoc.Close True`

Comment: Thanks sorry about the code dump.


This is the relevant code. The close the form line comes AFTER the save line, so the document is saved prior to that.
If I use sendKeys to accomplish the same thing or if I do it manually it does stick and saves like it is supposed to.


'            'All checkboxes to checked
                objAcroApp.Show

                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(22)).Value = 1
                objJSO.GetField(strFieldNames(23)).Value = 1
.......................